# Add Route to ajax Link?

Tags: zend-framework

I am still very new to Zend Framework and work on my first small Project. I have now come across from Routing, which is a great tool. Unfortunately I do not get it to run on my Ajax Link. I also can't find any information about it. Is there a way to add routes to an Ajax Link? Thank you very much in advance for any hint. Below is my try, but no sucess.

```
echo $this->ajaxLink("Remove",array('article' =>$this->escape($entry->id),'deleteB',true),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your ajax link should point just as normal link to the action in your controller. The only thing you need to do is disable rendering view which is by adding:

```
// path/ExampleController.php
public function removeAction()
{
    // Disable layout
    $this->_helper->layout->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();

    // Your code to remove goes below
}
```

In my opinion ajax does not need special route. Hope that helps somehow

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. I suppose you are right, that Ajax does not need a special route, I guess I went a bit crazy with this now, going throught the Sourcecode and replacing each URL with a route. I just wanted to check if I do things right. Thank you very much again !

Answer (score 0):

In the docs there doesn't seem to be any info on passing a route name as a parameter, at least I cannot find any - I'd be happy to be proven wrong.

I guess you can work around this problem for now, constructing the `$url` with the `url()` view helper and passing it then to the `ajaxLink` helper. Check out the ZF documentation page to make sure you pass the right parameters in the right places.

Comment: Mmh, I think you are right, I have checked the Docs again and also the ajaxLink.php file, but nothing looks like it takes routes. Well, I just thought to get a quick feedback on this, before I oversee something again. Now I just have another Problem with the ajax Link and a dialog Box, but I suppose I should write this as a new question. Thank you very much again for your help !